# How to include some deps and source codes in Gradle conditionally

Tags: maven, gradle

In a Maven project, it is easy to add extra deps and include extra source codes via defining a new Maven profile.

How to do the following things in a Gradle project.

- Includes extra deps
- Includes another source codes directory

And for example, use an extra property existence(eg. add to command line) to decide to activate it or not. I am not sure the best way in Gradle world.

Comment: That is in Maven also not the best idea to add code via profile...

Comment: If I need add some codes conditionally(such as for specific application servers), not in a profile, is there any other better ways to do it? Ok, this is not related to my problem.

Comment: Separate modules which container specifics for app servers...

Answer (score 1):

**I am not recommending your approach.**

But it can be done via - project properties from gradle command line and `groovy if (condition) { }` for dependencies and multiple sourceset defs

on command line

```
gradle build -PbProfile=extra1
```

```
ext.buildFlag = 'default'
if (project.hasProperty('bProfile')) {
    ext.buildFlag = property('bProfile')
}
println "running profile - ${buildFlag}"


dependencies {
    //common-deps
    if ("extra1".equals(buildFlag)) {
        //extra deps
    }
}

if ("extra1".equals(buildFlag)) {
    //custom sourceset def
} // more else if needed
```

Answer (score 1):

I use conditionally applied sub-configurations. This is done thru the `apply from` directive:

```
if (project.hasProperty('browsers')) {
  ext.browsers.split(',').each {
    def browser = it.trim()
    if (browser) {
      apply from: "${browser}Deps.gradle"
    }
  }
}
```

This block checks for specification of the `browsers` property (either from `gradle.properties` or the `-P` command line argument). If this property is defined, I split the property's value on commas and apply sub-configurations whose names conform to the pattern `<browser>Deps.gradle`.

The project in which I use this pattern is [here](https://github.com/sbabcoc/Selenium-Foundation)